# Handling an Ajax call with .load() in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make an Ajax call to render the content within my show action on my index page after clicking a link. So far I have a solution where I use jQuery's `.load()` method but I have encountered an issue where it is loading my assets twice and duplicates content.

After looking at the following setup, is there a better way to get this to work (I have read that people create js.erb files ?) or fix what I have in place currently

Controller

```
def show
  @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
end
```

Index page

```
<!-- Portfolio Section -->    
<section id="portfolio" class="section">
<div class="container">
  <div class="title col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
    <h1>Our <strong>Portfolio</strong></h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Portfolio Filters -->
  <ul id="filters">
    <li class="filter" data-filter="all">All</li>
      <li class="filter" data-filter="Plastering">Plastering</li>
      <li class="filter" data-filter="Plumbing">Plumbing</li>
      <li class="filter" data-filter="Bathroom Fitting">Bathroom Fitting</li>
      <li class="filter" data-filter="Construction">Construction</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- End Portfolio Filters -->
</div>
<div class="portfolio-top"></div> 
<!-- Portfolio Grid -->
<ul id="portfolio-grid">
  <li class="mix Plastering mix_all">
    <img alt="Gallery portfolio home" class="open-project" src="http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/gallery_images/38/gallery_portfolio_home.jpg?1397059278" />
    <a href='/galleries/22' class="open-project">
      <div class="project-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i>
        <span class="project-name">Test</span>
        <span>Plastering</span>         
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- End Portfolio Grid -->
<!-- Ajax Loaded Portfolio -->
<div id="project-extended">
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="project-controls">
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="close-project">
          <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="project-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Ajax Loaded Portfolio -->
<div class="portfolio-bottom"></div>
```

Show action

```
<div id="project">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="project-media">
    <div class="project-slider">
       <ul class="slides">
        <% @gallery.gallery_images.each do |image| %>
          <li><%= image_tag(image.photo.url(:gallery_flexslider)) %>
              <p class="flex-caption"><%= image.gallery_category.name %></p>  
            </li>
        <% end %>
       </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="project-info">
   <h1><%= @gallery.title %></h1>
  </div>

<div class="project-category">
  <span class="border"></span>
  <span><%= @gallery.category.name %></span>
  <span class="border"></span>
 </div>
  <p class="center"><%= @gallery.overview %></p>

 </div>
</div><!--/#project -->
```

So the idea here is the show action content appends itself within #project-content on the index page

js

```
  //Portfolio Project Loading
  $('.open-project').click(function(){
    var projectUrl = $(this).attr("href");   

    $('#project-content').animate({opacity:0}, 400,function(){
    $("#project-content").load(projectUrl);
    $('#project-content').delay(400).animate({opacity:1}, 400);
  });  

  //Project Page Open
    $('#project-extended').slideUp(600, function(){
    $('#project-extended').addClass('open');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".portfolio-bottom").offset().top }, 900);
    }).delay(500).slideDown(600,function(){          
      $('#project-content').fadeIn('slow',function(){
        if ($('.project-slider').length > 0) {
        initProjectSlider();
      }
    });
   });

   return false;       

   });
```

What is the best way to handle this?

### Edit

Assets being loaded twice

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by you loading your layout with the XHR request. You should try this:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
layout Proc.new {|controller| controller.request.xhr? ? false : "application" }
```